# Model Builder ArcGis Iterate file and rename files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase

I want to go through a folder and subfolders to copy some files in a gdb. At the moment I have tried to do it using the iterator file and the Copy tool. The problem is all the files have the same name, then I would need to rename and give them a only name before to copy them in the gdb.

I am not too sure how I could rename them automatically, any advice?

Comment: Advice - move to arcpy and abandon ModelBuilder. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don´t think I would be able to do it ;) . My knowledge in  phyton is even worse than in Model Builder!

Comment: It's easier to learn Python than ModelBuilder, you will manage it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model builder has two built in system variables that you can use with in-line variable substitution to automatically rename files and give them unique names.

From the ESRI documentation on [Examples of in-line variable substitution with ModelBuilder system variables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000060000000):

**Using the %i% system variable with in-line variable substitution**
[image]

**Using the %n% system variable with in-line variable substitution**

[image]

If you are using [Iterate Feature Classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00400000000r000000), you could combine the Name variable with the system variable in some tool's output parameter:

```
C:\path\to\your.gdb\%Name%_%n%
```